# ASP.NET MVC - SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sockets, email, server

I am currently creating an ASP.Net MVC web application on .NET 6 .The server im using is IIS local server from visual studio. I also use FluentEmail.core and FluentEmail.server packages and when i try to send an email i get this error. The project is on a flash drive and i work on it on maby 5 diffrent computers and my personal laptop. I tryed downloading the project on the computer/laptop but still i have the same error. Please help :D

This is the html form :

```
<form class="row contact_form" action="/Email/SendEmail" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <input type = "hidden" id = "controler" value = "@ViewBag.Controler"/>
                    <input type = "hidden" id = "action" value = "@ViewBag.Action"/>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your name'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter email address'">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Enter Subject" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Subject'">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="1" placeholder="Enter Message" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Message'"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="primary-btn">Send Message</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And this is the functionality on the controler (C#) :\

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SendEmail(string controler, string action , string name , string subject , string message , string email)
    {
        var sender = new SmtpSender(() => new SmtpClient("localhost")
        {
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Port = 465
        });

        Email.DefaultSender = sender;

        var emailToSend = Email
            .From(email, name)
            .To("autopoint2022@abv.bg")
            .Subject(subject)
            .Body(message);

        emailToSend.Send();
        //Incoming Server (Входящ сървър POP3): pop3.abv.bg – port: 995 TLS/SSL
        //Outgoing Server (Изходящ сървър SMTP): smtp.abv.bg – port: 465 TLS/SSL


        return RedirectToAction(controler, action);
    }
```

Just in case this is my launchSettings.json :

[image]

Ive expected the controler to send email to the specified email but ive got the error.

Comment: could you try running Visual Studio as admin?

Comment: still get the error